# xpages extlib dialog box. Need to capture when user presess escape key or clicks the X

Tags: dialog, xpages

I have a dialog box that works great if the user presses the OK or Cancel Buttons.  However, if they press the Escape Key or Click the X to close the dialog, I need to run some code.  I have tried putting code in the onHide and onClose and onUnload events to no avail.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

//  partial code listing . . .

```
<xe:dialog id="dialogUserCreds"
     title="#{javascript:viewScope.dialogUserCredsTitle;}">
    <xe:this.onHide><![CDATA[
       var url = "/xpVendorApplication.xsp";
       context.redirectToPage(url);]]>
        </xe:this.onHide>
    <xe:this.onClose><![CDATA[
           var url = "/xpVendorApplication.xsp";
           context.redirectToPage(url);]]>
         </xe:this.onClose>
</xe:dialog>
```

Comment: I found the onHide event is CSJS and the first alert does fire but neitherm forms of redirects work nor does the other alert fire.

<xe:this.onHide><![CDATA[
if( "#{javascript:viewScope.reloadParent}" == "yes" )
{
 alert( "before" );
// externalCtx = facesContext.getExternalContext();
// externalCtx.redirect("http://www.liebermanmanagement.com");
 var url = "/xpVendorApplication.xsp";
 context.redirectToPage(url);
 alert( "after" );
}
]]></xe:this.onHide>

Answer (score 2):

As you mention in your comment you have found the CSJS event of onHide(). This only accepts client side javascript but your partial code listing shows that you are trying to use server side javascript.

You will need to use a window.location(url) call to do the CSJS redirect in this case.